# How do I make a component go above the Tab menu?

Tags: codenameone

[image: This is what I have right now]
[image: This is what I want it to be]

When I click the "Tabs" component, it shows it as the whole thing around the edges (except the top part that says "Interactive Stories").

I want to know how I'd make the MultiButton go just above the menu at the bottom of the "Tabs" component. So an area with a BorderLayout and when I set it's layout constraint to "South", I want is so that it's above the menu, not underneath it. Because if I previously tried to just do that, the menu part of "Tabs" would overlap it.

I've already watched the "HOW DO I - POSITIONING COMPONENTS USING LAYOUT MANAGERS" video and that didn't explain what I want; if it did, I didn't catch it.

Here's the github repo if that'd help at all: https://github.com/gogobebe2/InteractiveStories

If you need me to clarify things, since I admit it may not be good english, please tell me. I'm determined to fix this. Thanks heaps :)

Edit: Solved! Opened the theme.res file, went to the constants tab in the theme and removed the tabsOnTopBool constant boolean. Big thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/756809/shai-almog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tabs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Tabs.html) component has a special mode that is activated in the leather theme to allow the "arrow effect" to overlay on top of the UI. It then adds padding to the bottom of the content pane to allow you to scroll more within the tab.

It uses the theme constant `tabsOnTopBool=true` to do that and if this is the case it uses a special form of `BorderLayout`:

```
border.setCenterBehavior(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_TOTAL_BELOW);
```

If you check out the [docs for CENTER_BEHAVIOR_TOTAL_BELOW](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/BorderLayout.html#CENTER_BEHAVIOR_TOTAL_BELOW) you will see:

> The center component takes up the entire screens and the sides are
>   automatically placed on top of it thus creating a layered effect

This is somewhat undocumented so I'm adding the documentation of this to my task list...

Comment: Thankyou. 2 questions though. How would I get the border instance from the Tabs component [Which I got with findTabs()]? Also where would I set the center behavior/code that stuff? Do I set it inside initVars(Resources res) inside StateMachine.java? Sorry if this a beginner question, this is my first codename one app.

Comment: You don't need the border instance. Open the theme, go to the constants tab in the theme and flip `tabsOnTopBool` to `false`.

Comment: Yay! Now that I read over your question I understand. Thankyou very much Shai, I'm a big fan of your work :)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with placing it at the South in the Tab. And infact that's the best way to do it.

You can give the **Story Maker** container a unique styling, let's say `ContainerBottomMargin2` that has 2mm bottom margin or padding. This will push the container up a bit to avoid overlapping.

You can also style your **TabsContainer** to have 2mm top padding.

Because North, South, East and West, all have more priority over center, the Tab buttons will always cover components at the TabbedPane if possible. As the buttons are sitting in the South and you are adding your contents to the center.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it right or not but I created a new "Unselected" UIID type called ContainerBottomMargin2 and went to the margin tab, unticked "Derive" and added 2 Millimetres to the bottom. I then went to the "TabsContaner", unticked the "Derive" box and changed padding to have 2 Milimeters at the top. It didn't work :/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1sAp1jE.jpg and http://i.imgur.com/5HQaz38.jpg show the blue line of where it is now.